# Kubernetes TLS issue

Tags: kubernetes, tls1.2

Im having some issues when building my Kubernetes Cluster.

Whenever I try to run a kubectl command, or my ansible scrips does, it gets the following error:

> Unable to connect to the server: tls: either ServerName or
>   InsecureSkipVerify must be specified in the tls.Config

Not from a script or by hand can anything execute the kubectl command, yet the apiserver pod is running.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably either haven't specified the server name or the CA certificate, or specified an incorrect one.

Make sure you have specified the correct CA and server name.